# Google play does not allow me to post my app

Tags: android

Google Play said : Warnings You imported an APK file that uses Google Play Services version 4030500. This APK file will only work with Android APIs level 9 or higher. You should not use this version of Google Play Services unless you have set the minSdkVersion value to 9 or higher in your manifest file. Your APK uses permissions that require privacy policies: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)

Comment: dont's spam with irrelevant tags

Comment: I'm not do spam sir

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning.

Comment: you did. neither `eclipse` nor `javascript` were related to your question

Comment: You've added `eclipse` and `javascript` tags to your question, which don't relate to your question. That's what Marcin Orlowski means

Comment: OKay sir i'm so sorry because i'm newbie in stackoverflow i don't know it before sorry again

Comment: And Google App Engine definitely has nothing to do with this post....

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, go to `build.gradle` and try to change the `minSdkVersion` to level 9 like this:

`minSdkVersion 9`

Comment: Did that helped you?